# Upload file to Amazon S3 bucket with shell script & curl command

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

I did a search through old questions and did find a couple that touched on this subject but they did not provide a resolution for my issue.  Trying to upload a file to an Amazon S3 bucket with a shell script set up in Secure Shell (Linux).  The script receives no errors & appears to work, however the file does not show up in the Amazon S3 bucket.  This is the script that I am using (hidden are actual values but removed for security purposes):

```
"OUT_FILE="hidden"
S3_BUCKET="hidden"
S3KEY="hidden"
S3SECRET="hidden"

FUNC_S3_UPLOAD()

#upload data to S3

{

source_file="$OUT_FILE"
resource="/${S3_BUCKET}/${source_file}"
contentType="application/csv"
dateValue=$(date -R)
stringToSign="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
signature=$(echo -en "${stringToSign}" | openssl sha1 -hmac "${S3SECRET}"         -binary | base64)

curl -X PUT -T "${source_file}" \
  -H "Host: $https://s3.amazonaws.com/{S3_BUCKET}" \
  -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${S3KEY}:${signature}" \

  https://s3.amazonaws.com/"$S3_BUCKET"/"$OUT_FILE"

}
```

The above is based on information obtained (below) from the the 3rd party vendor whose Amazon S3 bucket we are trying to upload to.

Required uploads prefix (And Full IAM username): importer-production-missouriwestern

Upload Locations:

```
HTTPS Example: https://s3.amazonaws.com/handshake-importer-uploads/importer-production-missouriwestern/yourobjectnamehere.csv


S3 Example: aws s3 cp /your/local/dir/test.csv s3://handshake-importer-uploads/importer-production-missouriwestern/test.csv
```

I did try the following script layout also with the same results:

```
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret}  -binary | base64`
curl -m 6000 -S -v -X PUT -T "${file}" \
    -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
    -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
    -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
    -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
    https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file}
```

Comment: Why not use the AWS CLI tool?

Comment: You're missing something. I would guess that an error code and message was generated and you're not seeing those, or, less likely perhaps, the file was indeed uploaded to S3 but you're looking in the wrong place or some other process has moved/deleted the file.

Comment: Our computer system is hosted by Ellucian and they will not allow me to use CLI.  I don't know the reasoning behind that.